# How to add multiple prices to one product?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, multiple

I want to set up a gift card product that has 3 point prices for the customer to choose from.

Product 1 - $100
Product 2 - $150
Product 3 - $200

Is there an option to do this on the backend? If not, how can I possibly do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

This is a feature available in Magento Enterprise:

1. Create a gift card product type

[image]

2. Under `Prices` enter the stepped prices you desire:

[image]

3. Save and view your product:

[image]

Comment: I get an error "Duplicate website group price customer group." This is shown when I am trying to set the prices

Comment: This only happens when you have the same product priced differently in different store scopes. Remove prices everywhere, set the price globally, and retry.

Comment: I can try but it seems your screenshot is different from my I guess I don't have the Enterprise version? Instead of "Amounts", mine says "Group Price".

Comment: My Magento does not have the Gift Card product type, that was the problem. How did you have that option? Is it an extension?

Comment: It is a feature of Magento Enterprise. While my answer is technically correct, it looks like you may have to rely on a third party extension.